# How do I achieve a pivot report with a dynamic columns in Crystal Reports for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, pivot

I have a stored procedure (SQL), it is make with a **pivot** query with **dynamic columns**. Some querys generate 2 or more columns, it all depends by the parameter. How do I achieve a **report** in **Crystal Reports** for **Visual Studio** (C# or VB) with this dynamic columns pivot?

Comment: sorry I think I got your question. So don't worry by the below answer. So my understanding you want to pass the columns into your SP but as one parameter?

Comment: Don't worry, @mvisser . _The problem is not the Stored Procedure_, it generates the correct information that I need; but, **How I put the result of the Stored Procedure in a report in Crystal Report for Visual Studio?**

Comment: I know in SSRS this is not possible. You have to pre-define the columns.  but you could hide the columns.

Comment: I had thought that, @mvisser, but the name of the dynamic columns changes drastically and is defined by the user. Anyway, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this, and this is how I did it for future similar problems:

- First. My stored procedure makes a query with a pivot with dynamic columns. I had to **remove the pivot** from my query, so only select the 3 same columns with a lot of rows.

The results (without pivot) is like this:

```
ClaveLMG Calificacion   Resultado
i7p-TP2 P1_1Excelente   100.0
i7p-TP2 P1_2Bueno       0.0
i7p-TP2 P1_3Regular     0.0
i7p-TP2 P1_4Malo        0.0
78-BD1  P1_1Excelente   100.0
78-BD1  P1_2Bueno       0.0
78-BD1  P1_3Regular     0.0
78-BD1  P1_4Malo        0.0
41-TP2  P1_1Excelente   100.0
41-TP2  P1_2Bueno       0.0
41-TP2  P1_3Regular     0.0
41-TP2  P1_4Malo        0.0
42-TC2  P1_1Excelente   100.0
42-TC2  P1_2Bueno       0.0
42-TC2  P1_3Regular     0.0
42-TC2  P1_4Malo        0.0
```

- Doing a research from how to use Crystal Reports, when you create a report from Crystal Report, yo have to select an assistant. I select **Crosstabs**.
- Finally, after select my stored procedure (without pivot), in the crosstab assistant, you have to add *rows*, *columns*, and *summary fields* from the fields that generate my stored procedure. Almost like when you coding a pivot.

  `____________   i7p-TP2    78-BD1      41-TP2      42-TC2
   P1_1Excelente  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
   P1_2Bueno      0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
   P1_3Regular    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
   P1_4Malo       0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000`

The result from this is a beatiful report like a pivot query.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done. Here is an example below.

```
DECLARE @ColumnString varchar(200), 
    @sql varchar(1000)


CREATE TABLE #ColumnValue
(
  Value varchar(500)
)

INSERT INTO #ColumnValue (Value)
SELECT DISTINCT '[' + 'value' + Convert(Varchar(20),ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by id Order by id )) + ']'
FROM Test

SELECT @ColumnString = COALESCE(@ColumnString + ',', '') + Value
FROM #ColumnValue
Drop table #ColumnValue



SET @sql =
'
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
        id,name,val,''value'' + Convert(Varchar(20),ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by id Order by id ))as [values]
FROM Test
) AS P
    PIVOT
(
    MAX(val) FOR [values] IN ('+@ColumnString+')
) AS pv
'

--print @sql 
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Dig the dynamic Pivot, but I think OP already has a dynamic pivot in SQL and is looking how to incorporate the dynamic results in Crystal Reports

Comment: yeah I mis understood.

Comment: Almost posted my stored procedure as well.